# Generate probabilities of a normal distribution under special condition

Tags: r, normal-distribution

In my work, I need to use normal distribution in order to generate probabilities, where sum of these probabilities are less than or equal to 1, it means:

generate `P1,P2,..,Pt` where `P1+P2+..+Pt <= 1`
I want to do that with `R`, but I don't know exactly how should I do that.

Comment: What exactly has to be normal ? The vector (P1,...Pn) ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I want to use normal distribution as a function in my work. my function is like that: F :{1,...,t} -> {P1,P2,..,Pt}. I want to place normal distribution over this function.

Comment: it sounds like these might be compositional data.  Are the individual elements required to be >=0?

Comment: "Using a normal distribution to generate probabilities" does not make very much sense: probabilities are in [0, 1] but normal RVs have support ]-inf, +inf[. Are you thinking of a truncated normal with support [0, 1]?

Comment: actually, the goal is generating transition function like F:{1,2..,t} -> {P1,P2,..,Pt}. for this purpose normal distribution is placed over function F. since Pi s are probabilities, for each Pi, 0 <= Pi <= 1 and also P1+P2+..+Pt <= 1

Comment: I think you may be looking for something like the additive log-ratio transformation: see the `robCompositions` or `rgr` packages ... (oops, sorry, that will generate values that sum to exactly 1, not <=1)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about what you are asking?

```
x <- rnorm(100)
Fn <- ecdf(x)
#plot(Fn)
Fn(max(x))
> Fn(max(x))
[1] 1
```

Comment: actually, the goal is generating transition function like F:{1,2..,t} -> {P1,P2,..,Pt}. for this purpose normal distribution is placed over function F. since Pi s are probabilities, for each Pi, 0 <= Pi <= 1 and also P1+P2+..+Pt <= 1.

Comment: @Peggy Ok. Adding this text to your question would be interesting. Provide if possible online references and examples. Show your approach (if any) until now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly. If you want to generate 4 probabilities from 4 normal random variables, you can do

```
x <- rnorm(4)
p <- exp(x)/sum(exp(x))
all(p<1) == TRUE
sum(p) == 1
```

If you want a sum that's less than or equal to 1, here's a transformation that may work (not sure how to make it pretty).

```
x <- rnorm(4)
p <- exp(x)/sum(exp(x))
b<-numeric(4)
b[1]<-p[1]
b[2]<-p[2]-p[1]*p[2]
b[3]<-p[3]-p[2]*p[3]+p[1]*p[2]*p[3]
b[4]<-p[4]-p[3]*p[4]+p[2]*p[3]*p[4]-p[1]*p[2]*p[3]*p[4]
all(b<1) == TRUE
sum(b) <= 1
```

Although i'm worried this method may have a bias. Right now the `p`'s sum to 1. It would be better if there were a way to make each `p` a number 0-1 (so the sum may be 0-4).

Comment: thank you, this is what I need, with a slight different; sum(p)<=1

Comment: @Peggy Well, if you need `n` probabilities, then i might choose `n+1` normal random variables and do the same translation, then only take the first `n` values. So the extra variable determines how far you are away from 1.

Comment: @Peggy i've updated my answer with a possible transformation that does not require an extra random variable

Comment: thank you, but I can't understand why did you use this way of generating for vector b.

Comment: @Peggy Sorry, it is a bit ridiculous. The idea is to thing of cutting up a 1 meter stick. If the first probability is .25, I'll cut off 25% of the stick. If the next probability is .1, i'll cut off 10% of what ever remains of the stick. If the next probability is .45, i'll cut off 45% of what remains. And finally i'll take 20% of what remains. That means i'll have four pieces I cut off, and some left over (possibly). So the lengths of the sticks i cut off are the new probabilities. I expanded the terms above, but I probably should have written them differently.